# Network Drive using directory-tree package nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory-tree

I am trying to map a network drive using [directory tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree) package in nodejs. It works perfectly when the files is in one of my local drives, but i have trouble acessing my network drive. I want to be able to form a json file to represent the directory tree of that drive and display this in my front end. Is this something i can do for a network drive? Here is my code

```
router.get('/files', function (req, res) {

    var tree = dirTree('X:/Images');
    res.send(tree);
});
```

My network drive is mapped to X

Comment: Please show was what you have tried so far

Comment: Sure thing, ill update the question

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is something you can do provided you have network access to that drive with the user running the application. Theres no implementation difference in accessing a mapped network drive and a folder on your local drive, you just need the correct permissions.

If you just ran your code you would see pretty quickly if it works.

Comment: Thanks! My code does work, like i said in the question it worked perfectly for my local drive, and you are right there seems to be some permission issue with the drive. Thanks. I dont get why i got so many down votes.